# Are questions about animal communication on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions about human-animal communication on-topic here?

Of course, still with regards to *language learning*. (e.g. learning to communicate with animals, gorillas learning sign language, etc.)

Comment: As a general aside, I think it's not very productive to ask these questions before the situation actually arises. Any rules we make now will be based on uneducated guesses. It will be much more meaningful to make a decision about this topic if/when we're actually faced with a relevant question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, no.

If a question about animal communication relates to language learning (perhaps we learn how to do language training based on observations of animal communication?), why not?

If you're asking about how to teach animals human language, that may be a grey area.  I can't imagine there being either a) enough expertise among us to answer such questions, or b) enough interest in the topic for there to be questions about it. But if I'm proven wrong, I'm completely willing to address that issue if/when it arises.

So TLDR: My suggestion is to wait until it becomes an issue to address it.

Comment: Sounds good. I was pretty sure it wasn't going to be on-topic. :P Thanks.